# Mostrar campos de um json em tela

Tags: angular

Recebo seguinte Json:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de mostrar em tela o seguintes campos em uma tabela:

> standings>0>table>Todos o retornos de 0 a n

Oque tenho até agora é:

```
<div *ngFor="let tabelas of campeonato.standings | keyvalue">
<div >
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-if="tabelas.value.type == TOTAL ">
            <tr>
                <td>{{tabelas.value.type}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="text-center">
                    <h4>Nenhum Campeonato Encontrado.</h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Mas não estou conseguindo chegar até os campos da `table`

Comment: O problema está no `ngFor`, tente assim: `*ngFor="let tabelas of campeonato.standings[0].table | keyvalue"`

Comment: Recebi o seguinte erro `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: porque vc esta usando o keyvalue pipe?

Comment: Estava tentando utilizar a key para poder fazer um if por `standings[0]`

Comment: Tenta *ngFor="let tabelas of campeonato.standings[0].table" sem o keyvalue. E coloca um ngIf campeonato em um div acima desse ngFOr para certificar que a resposta do backend chegou.

Comment: @EduardoVargas continua o mesmo problema, `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, ele está fazendo o foreach corretamente, mas esse erro continua

Comment: é pq ele é undefined até chegar a resposta do back, pra resolver ou vc inicianilza ele vazio de alguma forma ou faz um ngif ao redor dele